# Share proxy/sequences references between ESBConfiguration projects

Tags: wso2-integration-studio, wso2-esb

We have the following problematic :
we have an ESB Configuration project containing proxies/sequences that we want to reuse inside an other ESB Configuration Project (we just want to reference them not to copy) and finally build them inside the same CAR.
How can we do it with DeveloperStudio/maven ?

Tks
Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

All developer studio projects are fully maven comfortable . Please follow the following steps to create projects

1. Create maven [multi-module](https://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS350/Using+Maven+with+Developer+Studio#UsingMavenwithDeveloperStudio-WorkingwithMavenMultiModuleprojects) project.
2. Then create the ESB configuration project(As a best practice do it inside the
   Multi-module project.).
3. Create relevant ESB artifact(Proxy/Sequence) inside that ESB config project.
4. Finally create the Composite application project (As a best practice do it inside the
       Multi-module project too).

Now go to the maven multi-module project location and build it(mvn clean install)
Once build succeed ,you can find the Car file inside composite application target directory

You not need to build project by project just build the multi-module project only.

Hope this help !!